# ReactJs if div contains className set negative tabindex to childrens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabindex

I am new to ReactJs. I am trying to avoid the keyboard tab focus event for `<input>`, `<a>` elements for specific div's. If div contains `.text1` class name text1 div children elements should not be focussed.

In React I have done add/remove css className using props.

```
className={`${style.column5} ${ isActiveDiv ? style.column5Active : style.noTabindex }`}
```

I achieve this below output using jQuery. But, how do I do that in ReactJs?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 if ($(".text1").length){
      $(".text1 input, .text1 a").attr("tabindex", "-1");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="text">
  
  </div>
  <div class="text1">
      <input type="text" />
      <a href="#">Anchor Tag</a>
  </div>
  <div class="text2">
      <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="text3">
      <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What owns the mark-up, the component or something you have in a public.html file?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-bartik-xezn5

Comment: I see so the way you plan on integrating this, do you have control on how the mark-up is created. Like what if you wanted to iterate over some sort of array to create these elements?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo These elements are not loaded from array. These elements are static

Comment: Sweet. Just created a sandbox for you. Will show you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a couple ways you can handle this. The static way would be just pass in a `tabIndex` property of -1 to those elements you don't want to focus:

```
<input type="text" tabIndex={-1} />
```

The dynamic way would be to find all elements that contain a class of `text1` and then dynamically updating the tabIndex property of all their child elements. You can try something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const parentRef = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    //get children elements
    const refChildren = Object.values(parentRef.current.children);
    //find children with class of text1
    const childrenWithText1Class = refChildren.filter(
      child => child.className === "text1"
    );
    //find children's children to neglect
    const childrensChildren = childrenWithText1Class.flatMap(child =>
      Object.values(child.children)
    );

    const disableList = ["a", "input", "select", "textarea", "button"];

    //neglect children
    childrensChildren.forEach(elem => {
      if (disableList.includes(elem.nodeName.toLowerCase())) {
        elem.tabIndex = -1;
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="parent" ref={parentRef}>
      <div class="text" />
      <div class="text1">
        <input type="text" />
        <a href="#">Anchor Tag</a>
        <select />
        <textarea />
        <audio controls />
        <button>Check</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text2">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="text3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-sara-blp9q
You can test it by clicking into the `div` (background) with the `text1` class and try tabbing. You'll see that you actually end up skipping over to the next block.

Comment: Thanks. But in your code you have added `tabindex=-1` to all children elements. In my case I need to add `tabindex=-1` to `a`, `button`, `input`, `select` and `textarea` only. https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-firefly-5b6kx . Not div, span, p elements

Comment: Gotcha, what we can do is add a simple list of elements we can reference to determine whether the iterated element should be non-focusable. I've updated the existing sandbox and will update the code above @KaruppiahRK